# Python Exception Safe Pickle Use

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

#### Background

I've inherited a code base with a lot of `try ... except:` clauses. Most of them are way too broad, and make it a pain to debug. I've been going through and changing each to the most reasonable form, which usually involves removing it or specifying the exception(s).

#### Problem

But I'm a little stumped by this one:

```
try:
    with open(self.session_filename, "rb") as f:
        data = cPickle.loads(zlib.decompress(f.read()))
except:
    # we didn't need your file anyway!
    return
```

I want to handle the exceptions specifically, but the [Python docs on Pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) say:

> exception pickle.UnpicklingError
>
> This exception is raised when there is a problem unpickling an
>   object. Note that **other exceptions may also be raised during
>   unpickling, including (but not necessarily limited to)** `AttributeError`,
>   `EOFError`, `ImportError`, and `IndexError`.

Translation: The method might throw anything!

So apparently it can raise arbitrary exceptions, which makes it hard to handle them specifically.

How can I most reasonably deal with this situation, keeping the following goals in mind:

1. I want to catch all exceptions resulting from a bad filename or other OS issues, or a bad format.
2. I don't want to be overly broad and thus hide other issues.
3. I'd prefer not to read the implementation and try to parse out all the different potential exceptions. That would be implementation-dependent, possibly fail with updates, and take a lot of time.

It may be that not all can be fulfilled.

Comment: If you really don't want to narrow it down (and/or it's not relevant to do so), you could use `except Exception:`.

Comment: What do you mean by "exception safe"?  You can't know ahead of time whether it's possible to recover from every kind of exception while still finishing the unpickling (e.g., IOError due to some kind of disk failure).  What error conditions do you want to handle, and how do you want to handle them?

Comment: @BrenBarn by exception safe, I mean I want to handle the application and crash or move on with something besides an unhandled exception. In this case, I can just assume the pickling failed and abort what the method was trying to do (the method gives a 'best effort'). If different exceptions can give me more detailed information, I'd be interested.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm trying to avoid the overly broad exception. The all-exceptions approach could also catch, for example, a SIGINT from Ctrl+C, causing my application to lock up on the console and not quit when it should. `except Exception:` is the same as `except:`, and both give a warning in PyCharm (for good reason, too!).

Comment: No, it's not the same; it won't catch Ctrl-C, etc., which is why I suggested it. Read the exception hierarchy in the docs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nice, thank you! That's quite a bit safer, but still gives me a warning. I wonder what the risks are here.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not handling only the exceptions you want to handle and letting everything else go? If you're ok with the UnpicklingError, you can handle that, but if you get and ImportError, none of them may work; it may be worth only handling one or two specific exceptions and letting the rest go.

Comment: @opticaliqlusion (see edits) I want to handle all exceptions that might result from my environment (missing file, bad format, etc.), without hiding other exceptions. This code base has a lot of `try .. except:` clauses that make it a pain to debug, which is what I'm fighting against. I've been investigating each and trying to reduce it to the most reasonable form.

Comment: @JoshP In that case, I would recommend cascading exception handling. `try .. except UnpicklingException: .. except ImportError .. except EOFError .. except Excepton:` where each 'known' exception is handled with unknown exceptions having their own `except` block. Remember you can also do many at once: if there's one action for many exceptions `except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):`

Comment: @opticaliqlusion I would, but what's got me hung up is the docs saying 'including (but not necessarily limited to)' these exceptions. I can do all that, and apparently whoknowswhat can still be thrown. Maybe that's more normal than I realize, or just the risk I need to accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Breaking up the exceptions into several handlers may be what you want, with a catchall if you need it.

```
try:
    with open(self.session_filename, "rb") as f:
         data = cPickle.loads(zlib.decompress(f.read()))
except pickle.UnpicklingError as e:
    # normal, somewhat expected
    continue
except (AttributeError,  EOFError, ImportError, IndexError) as e:
    # secondary errors
    print(traceback.format_exc(e))
    continue
except Exception as e:
    # everything else, possibly fatal
    print(traceback.format_exc(e))
    return
```

Comment: Thank you! This will work for me for now. For this particular code bit, I also need to catch `IOError` for `open()` and `zlib.error` for `zlib.decompress()`. I take it the secondary exception clause is for semi-expected errors. Excellent compromise.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would try to handle only specific exceptions which is not really possible in this case: Who knows what exceptions could `cPickle.loads` throw in the future.

Where it is no possible to be more specific in the type of the exceptions I'd try to be more specific on the code block that I wrap in `try ... except`. For this example this could be like this:

```
with open(self.session_filename, "rb") as f:
    uncompressed_data = zlib.decompress(f.read())

try:
    data = cPickle.loads(uncompressed_data)
except cPickle.UnpicklingError:
    raise
except Exception as e:
    # Unpickling failed
    raise cPickle.UnpicklingError(repr(e))
```